# Query to rebuilt domain index

Tags: oracle, indexing, rebuild

```
Create or replace procedure REBUILD_X_TEXT
IS
Begin

 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX Schema.table_name rebuild parameters('REPLACE metadata sync(every "SYSDATE+15/1440")')'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX Schema.table_name NOPARALLEL';

End REBUILD_X_TEXT;
```

**It's giving an error:**  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "REPLACE" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return    returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or    like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk    member submultiset

Comment: To help get answers, please explain more what do you want to achieve and which is the context of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have single quotes in your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement, they need to be escaped by using two single quotes in a row like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REBUILD_X_TEXT
IS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX Schema.table_name rebuild parameters(''REPLACE metadata sync(every "SYSDATE+15/1440")'')';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX Schema.table_name NOPARALLEL';
END REBUILD_X_TEXT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easier to use [q-literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA__GUID-F5A8E669-897A-4759-9C7D-325B91D10886) for such things:

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
   ALTER INDEX Schema.table_name 
   rebuild parameters('REPLACE metadata 
                       sync(every "SYSDATE+15/1440")
                       '
                     )
   ]'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER INDEX Schema.table_name NOPARALLEL';
```